# Identifying string format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, search, string-formatting, prompt

I'm trying to solve a (simple) programming problem in Javascript and I can't figure out how to get it working. I have a program which starts by reading in a text string using prompt.

The program outputs either "Valid name" or "Invalid name", depending on whether the input names fit the required format, which is:

"last name, first name, middle initial"

where neither of the names can have more than 15 characters.

I know there's an easy way to do this, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I know several people with names longer than 15 characters. And several with no middle name (including myself) or several middle names.  It would be worth giving plenty of thought to the rules that determine what is or isn't valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `\w`, as it includes characters such as `_` and the nine digits. Consider the regular expression in the following test:

```
<script>
    if ("Nami, Guilherme, P".match(/^[A-Z][a-z]{1,14}, [A-Z][a-z]{1,14}, [A-Z]\.?$/)) {
        alert("Valid");
    }
    else {
        alert("Invalid");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'd make it case insensitive and allow more characters. Consider names like McDonald and O'Leary.

Answer (score 1):

use this regular expression:

```
/^\w{0,15}, \w{0,15}, \w{0,15}\.?$/.test(name)
```

Comment: Changed the last part to be a single digit (since it's the inital) and that can have an optional dot character

Comment: I didn't see a requirement for a minium of 5 characters for first and last name in the OP's requirements.

Comment: Quick! How many common names of 4 characters or less can you come up with in 1 minute? Jack Jill John Jon Tom Dick Hank Bob Joe Yi Lee Ivan ... I had a coworker whose actual legal name was just "T".

Comment: Ok, ok, don't beat me ;). Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (worked in my testing):

```
// assuming there are no commas in fields
var string = "last name, first name, middle initial", 
string_array = string.split(', '), 
length = string_array.length;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // changing string to 'blah, firrrrrsssttt nammme, bbbbb' outputs the alert message
    if (string_array[i].length > 15) alert('None of these can be more than 15 characters long. ' + string_array[i] + ' is too long');
}
```